# Edge webdriver fails on simple findElement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm using Selenium with java & TestNG for a year now for **testing a web application that is being build dynamically**. I'm testing Chrome, FF and IE11 and finally feeling ready to start Edge webdriver. After implementing the Edge driver that fits my OS  build (release 14393), and loaded a web page successfully,

I got an issue when trying to find an element using this xPath String:

```
".//*[contains(@class,'cbola-layer in-content-container-wrapper')]"
```

THE ERROR:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No such element

That's the simple code I'm using:

```
String layerTypeAttribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Consts.XPATH_STRING)).getAttribute("layer_attribute");
```

Is there a workaround for finding XPath?

Installed Java version is 1.8.0_73

**UPDATE:**
The test fail when trying to find the element regardless of the xPath. Tried also to find by class name and id and nothing came up.
Maybe it was important to say that I'm testing a web application that is being built by an **async script** that runs inside the page. I CAN find simple html on the page that is not related to my application, but I can't find my application and not even the static script tag that I manually put in the page.

[Screenshot of the web elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pOJ4.png)

Comment: may be edge driver is slow and takes more time to load then other browser,  how about putting some wait?

Comment: This string tells nothing about the possible issue. It is better to provide Consts.XPATH_STRING and the html (or dom part) snippet demostrating that the element does exist.

Comment: Are you able to find the element using browsers other than Edge?
Please can you also provide the value of `Consts.XPATH_STRING` and the html of the element you are trying to find?

Comment: You are totally right. here is the xPath: ".//*[contains(@class,'cbola-layer in-content-container-wrapper')]". Its working on Chrome, FF, and IE11.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a wait issue, because I can visually see the entire element in the page. (When the page loads, it builds my web app and then I start my test)

Comment: If you see the element but is not finding it, then you should also try to find him manually, maybe the page is interpreted differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement an explicit wait. So that the driver doesn't stop until the element is visible. You can change the 30 seconds to any amount you wish.

```
WebElement layerTypeAttribute = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath value")));
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal, but I'm afraid it's not a wait issue, because I can visually see the entire element in the page. (When the page loads, it builds my web app and then I start my test).

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted is referring to the xpath, so to be able to help you, please also post here:

- the full html for the element you are trying to locate
- the xpath you are actually using to locate the element

Also, I think because you declare a String variable (layerTypeAttribute) you should also fetch the element as string as well, so please add **.getAsString()** in the end!

```
String layerTypeAttribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Consts.XPATH_STRING))
.getAttribute("layer_attribute").getAsString();
```

Please let us know how it went.
Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @Xwris Stoixeia, but 1) I'm failing to find the webElement even before I can use the method. 2) the program "can't resolve the method .getAsString()".

Comment: No worries, there is something wrong with your xpath for sure. If you can get the html code of the element you are trying to locate, I'll try to help you.

Comment: Please check out my update above: "Tried also to find by class name and id and nothing came up." so I don't think its the xPath anymore, its finding the element built by a javascript.